# Keyboard navigation and the new nav don't mix

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, live-refresh, keyboard-shortcuts

I use keyboard shortcuts. *A lot*. But unfortunately, it appears that the new nav tries to steal the focus, *all the time*. It does so when loading the page, when new questions are being loaded, and when live-refresh adds the grey box to show new questions *can* be loaded.

When a new question comes in for my chosen (favourite) tags, a grey box at the top shows how many question will be available to  load. I click away from the tab box, then use <kbd>F</kbd> to load those questions. As soon as I hit that key two things happen:

- The new questions are added to the top of the list
- The keyboard focus switches to the tags box(!)

This means that the *next* time new questions come in, hitting <kbd>F</kbd> will start a new tag. *This is rather annoying*.

I noticed that loading the page for the first time *also* moves the focus to the tab box. Once I have set up my tabs I don't need to add more tags, so stealing the focus like this is not helpful. I want to navigate the questions, not have to first click outside the box each time.

Moreover, it looks as if incoming new questions is another trigger for the box to steal the focus. When I switch back to my browser tab to see if there are new questions, and there happen to be new questions, the focus is once again back to that text box.

Could the page please not do this? I'd rather not have to tab out each time.

Comment: The autofocus is by-design, we could disable it for users that have the "Enable keyboard shortcuts" set in their preferences (e.g. like you)

Comment: Even if I wasn't using keyboard shortcuts, it still interferes with being able to use the quick search in Firefox.

Comment: It also interferes with browser plugins that involve a lot of keyboard shortcuts (eg. Pentadactyl)

Comment: This also annoys me, but for a different reason; if I scroll the tab box off the top of the page (to fit more questions on) and hit `F5` to refresh, the focus-grabbing scrolls me back to the top of the page. If the box is off-screen, it shouldn't grab the focus.

Comment: It grabs focus on my tablet when watching the active tab, which automatically opens the keyboard. Don't grab focus @Sklivvz

Comment: @Sklivvz: only ever autofocus a text box if that's the *primary focus* of a page. The Google homepage can auto-focus the search box, a contact form can auto-focus the first field. But the tag box is *not* the primary focus of the question list. The *questions* are. Auto-focusing is a terrible idea here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be pushed out in rev `3799` on meta and `2916` on stack overflow.

Comment: And there was much rejoicing! :-D