# Saved tab isn't restored

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav, user-interface

It doesn't seem possible to save tabs.

Anytime I open [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), the tab I saved is missing. The only way I have to restore it is to use [this kind of link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20java%20arrays%20performance%20linux%20postgresql%20sql%20html%20css%20algorithm%20go%20jquery%20regex%20promise?mode=any) (which is subject to [at least another bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308886/keyboard-navigation-and-the-new-nav-dont-mix))

Comment: can you open up your browser's javascript console and type `localStorage.getItem("newNav")`? what does it say?

Comment: @Sklivvz `"{"questionLists":[{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/votes"},{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/active"},{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/tagged/javascript%20java%20arrays%20performance%20linux%20postgresql%20sql%20html%20css%20algorithm%20go%20jquery%20regex%20promise?mode=all"}]}"`

Comment: I thought I had this problem yesterday until I realized I wasn't hitting the "Save" button. (Although I did with the first one. No idea why I saved one tab and then *immediately* forgot about the button's existence.)

Comment: @BSMP I tried many times to save

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was just me. Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: side note: you will never get any result if you filter by all those tags via "and".

Comment: @Sklivvz I don't think I use a "and"

Comment: @DenysSéguret `mode=all` basically means `tag1 and tag2 ... and tagN`

Comment: @m0sa but that's not the tab I tried to save. Because the tab I tried to save obviously didn't get saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. It should have been obvious to me when Sklivvz's comment mentioned localStorage.

So the problem I had was that I was saving the new tab when connected to StackOverflow in https (using my link) and I was missing the tag when going to SO by typing `stackove` and letting my browser complete... and connect me in http.

As `http://stackoverflow.com` and `https://stackoverflow.com` are two different domains, their storages are distinct, and thus my localStorage based tab wasn't found.

BTW it's a little disappointing to have to set up the tabs on all my computers and  that there doesn't seem to be possible to have that tab the active one on arrival without setting up a link (link which makes the tab useless).

Comment: yes, I was also hoping that my custom tabs would be saved along with my user profile...

Answer (score 0):

> can you open up your browser's javascript console and type `localStorage.getItem("newNav")`? what does it say? – [Sklivvz♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz) [Oct 28 '15 at 14:03](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308953/saved-tab-isnt-restored/309084#comment263942_308953)

I see a fundamental problem with this approach.

You cannot retrieve save tabs across devices, I usually rely on direct links in the bookmarks section of my Internet Browser to get the view I want quickly, something like;

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-one%20or%20tag-two
```

to get my default view filtered by the tags I wanted, but with the new navigation this isn't possible and just creates a new tab which I find a bit fustrating. My workaround at the moment is to just set the bookmark to

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

and select the relevant saved tab, but then I realise this won't work if I'm on another device or using another Browser as `localStorage` is Browser dependant and so is also Device dependant *(given what I have read about `localStorage` before and it's consistency across Internet Browsers)*.

> **Update** Just tested on my iPad and Chrome does pick up the tabs so `localStorage` does sync across devices so not as much of an issue, although I imagine cross Browser won't work. Still doesn't solve the problem of directly linking to a tab though.