# Real-time notification causes navigation page to scroll

Tags: bug, notifications, new-nav

I'm using the [New Navigation Release Candidate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate?cb=1), and I view new questions in my SO favorite tags with https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags. Then I scroll down on the page. When a real-time notification occurs (**N new questions**), it causes the page to scroll back to the top, and I lose my place in the navigation page.

I could be wrong, but I don't think I noticed this until the latest revision to the New Navigation.

Comment: Could you post a screen grab? I'm unable to reproduce. Thanks!

Comment: What's a screen grab of a dynamic action? It would just show the page scrolled to the top.

Comment: I think this is related to the [auto focus](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308886/keyboard-navigation-and-the-new-nav-dont-mix) on the tags field at the top

Comment: Nevermind, I missread.

Comment: @Andy I think you may be right. It doesn't happen all the time, so I guess it only happens when I've done something to take the focus out of the tags box, like Cmd-click on a question.